# Unable to get values from webpage using Nightwatchjs

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

Using latest version of web driver and nightwatchjs.

Using the below code, I never get anything in gotTags.
If I set a breakpoint within:

```
browser.elementIdText(element, function (result) {
                        gotTags.push(result.value);
                        console.log(result.value);
});
```

It never breaks on it.

I know that the query works and returns 10 elements:

```
document.querySelector('iframe[src="about:blank"]').contentDocument.querySelectorAll('.gtm-debug-tags-fired-container .gtm-debug-tags-card-title')
```

The code:

```
browser
       .url(config.url)
       .waitForElementPresent('body', 5000)
       .waitForElementPresent('iframe[src="about:blank"]', 10000)
       .execute(function(){
                return document.querySelector('iframe[src="about:blank"]').contentDocument.querySelectorAll('.gtm-debug-tags-fired-container .gtm-debug-tags-card-title')
            }, function(elems){
                var element;

                for (var i = 0; i < elems.value.length; i++) {
                    element = elems.value[i].ELEMENT;

                    browser.elementIdText(element, function (result) {
                        gotTags.push(result.value);
                        console.log(result.value);
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Documentation http://nightwatchjs.org/api#execute  says, you're missing the second (or the third at the moment) parameter.

```
function(elems){
            var element;

            for (var i = 0; i < elems.value.length; i++) {
                element = elems.value[i].ELEMENT;

                browser.elementIdText(element, function (result) {
                    gotTags.push(result.value);
                    console.log(result.value);
                });
            }
```

This part has to be the third parameter, since the second is the args parameter for the function in the first parameter.

So, i think it must be like

```
.execute(function(){
            return document.querySelector('iframe[src="about:blank"]').contentDocument.querySelectorAll('.gtm-debug-tags-fired-container .gtm-debug-tags-card-title')
        }, [], function(elems){ // added [] here as second parameter
            var element;

            for (var i = 0; i < elems.value.length; i++) {
                element = elems.value[i].ELEMENT;

                browser.elementIdText(element, function (result) {
                    gotTags.push(result.value);
                    console.log(result.value);
                });
            }
```